# Python Class Location Variables

Tags: python, class, variables, localization

I wanted to decrease the players health but I was unsure if I was able to do this, sorry if this question is unclear but I am a new coder and am slowly get a grasp on how classes work. I think I need to make this more clear as I can.

```
class Health(object): 
#health of player and enemy
#input of the both health so it is able to
#be a preset for more combat

    def __init__(self, player, enemy):

        self.player = player
        self.enemy = enemy

class Attack_Type(object):
#making a attack type blueprint
#combat attacks can be modified

    def melee(self, target):
        #100% chance of landing hit
        if target == player:
            Health.player -= 1
            return Health.player
        elif target == enemy:
            Health.enemy -= 1
            return Health.enemy

test = Health(10,10)
enemy_melee = Attack_Type(Health.player)
```

My question is how do i access a variables value inside a class without making it global. Am i able to change the value of the class value within the class?
This Does Not change the players health because it can't access the players health but even when it does it does not return the value to the right place

I now to realise that it is much simpler to make the health a attribute, sorry everyone i do not fully understand how classes work! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Does `player_health = bridge.attack(player_health)` do what you want?

Comment: @Paul Rooney no the a trackback occurs saying 'player_health' is not defined on line 14

Comment: Ok. Sorry I assumed you weren't showing all your code. Is player health supposed to be an object of some sort or just an integer? Just add `player_health=0` anywhere before the last line. I don't get what you're trying to do though.

Comment: That's a very interesting use of classes, but I think you might have an easier time if you made `health` an attribute of a `Player` class rather than having a `Health` object containing everyone's health.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah you are right it is much easier to use a attribute outside of the class, what i was thinking in the beginning was a blueprint for a combat system. I am new to python and i wasn't sure if i was able to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps! :)

```
class Health:
    def __init__(self): #Constructor initializing the variables.
        self.player_health = 10
        self.enemy_health = 10

class Combat:
    #Attack function receives a health object called "hitter" 
    def attack(self, hitter):
        hitter.player_health -= 1   #Health Object hitter's player_health reduced by one. 
        return hitter

bridge = Combat() #Combat Object
hitter = Health() #Health Object

bridge.attack(hitter) #hitter.player_health is now 9.
```

Comment: thank you this helped a lot, i wasn't sure if i was able to do it. As i am new to python, but this helped a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You can check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) to learn more about object oriented programming in Python!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one incarnation.

```
class Health:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_health = 10
        self.enemy_health = 10


class Combat:
    def attack(self, health_obj):
        health_obj += -1
        return health_obj

bridge = Combat()
players = Health()

print(bridge.attack(players.player_health))
```